# How to find a Lyapunov function for this non-linear system?

Tags: control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Consider the system:

$$\dot{x}_1 = x_2 $$
$$\dot{x}_2 = -g(k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2),   k_1>0, k_2>0$$

where the nonlinearity g(·) is such that

$$g(y)y > 0, \forall y \neq 0 $$

$$lim_{|y| \to \infty} \int_{0}^{y} g(\alpha) d(\alpha) = +\infty $$

Using an appropriate Lyapunov function, show that the equilibrium x = 0 is globally asymptotically stable.

ATTEMPT:

I know if:

$$\dot{x}_2 = -f(x_1) - g(x_2)$$ then I can define Lyapunov function as:

$$V(x_1, x_2) = (\int_{0}^{x_1}f(x)dx) + 1/2x_2^2$$.

Then,

$$\dot{V(x_1, x_2)}= -x_2 g(x_2) <0$$

But here, the function $$g(k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2)$$ cannot be split into these two function of that depend on only $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively.
What should the choice of Lyapunov function be for this case?

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: Edited the question with what I know

Comment: Try to use the change of variables $z_1=x_1$ and $z_2=k_1x_1+k_2x_2$.

Comment: @RohanAgrawal, Have you managed to prove the global asymptotic stability with $V = \frac{1}{2} k_{2} z_{1}^{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}^{2}} z_{2}^{2}$?